# Modifying a program to Decrypt a message using a past encrypted alphabet on python

Tags: python, encryption

I need help in writing the second part to this program, which is almost complete. I finish writing the part in which an alphabet is encrypted, but now I find myself stuck in trying to use the new encryption as a sort of decoder ring, to decrypt a a random scrambled message that someone might input into the program.

So to makes this easier to understand, lets say the *encryption* part of this program gives you: **NHPWJXEYOZMAFUSCIGLVTDBKRQ**

Now someone would  type some random message encrypted using the new scrambled alphabet. So lets say someone types: **VYOL OL FR 1LV LJPGJV FJLLNEJ!**

Now the program that I need to write will have to use the scrambled alphabet to decoded the message and print: **THIS IS MY 1ST SECRET MESSAGE!**

If anyone can help, I'll appreciate it. If it still sounds confusing, just ask. Th program that I have is below:

```
           # ENCODE a secret message
            # Scramble the alphabet, read a secret message, encode it, print scrambled

            import random

            def main():

                encryption()

                decryption()

            def encryption():

                encrypt=["*"]*26   # all letters available
                print(encrypt)

                print("Alphabet:  ", end="")
                for numbah in range(26):
                    #converts numbah into a letter
                    letter = chr(numbah+65) # converts 0-25 --> 'A' = 'Z'

                    print(letter, end="")

                    #Reminder: find an empty position for that letter to be placed

                    notfound = True
                    while notfound:
                        possible_position = random.randint(0,25)
                        if encrypt[possible_position] == "*":
                            notfound = False
                    encrypt[possible_position] = letter

                print("\nScrambled: " , end="")
                for numbah in range(26):
                    print(encrypt[numbah], end="")

                print("\n\n")

                msg=input("Now, please type your secret message to encode: ")
                print("Your secret message:  " + msg)
                print("Your message encoded: ", end="")

                # reminder non alphabetic characters should 'float thru' unchanged!

                for alpha in msg.upper():
                    if alpha < "A" or alpha > "Z":
                        print(alpha, end="")
                    else:
                        print( encrypt[ ord(alpha) - 65], end="")

                print("\n")

            def decryption():

                scram_alph = input("Input the scrambled alphabet from the early prog:  ")

                scram_mess = input("Input the scrambled messgae you want decoded:  ")







            main()
```

Comment: @Staven: you shouldn't edit a question to add the [tag:homework] tag. See [the guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/150487).

Comment: @katrielalex OK, sorry about that. I didn't realize there's so much controversy around this topic (of the homework tag).

Comment: only the first part with the encryption was homework, I just wish to know about going further encase it might come up in the future

Answer (score 2):

There are functions in the Python standard library that make this task quite easy.  Have a look at [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`string.maketrans()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

```
>>> import string
>>> t = string.maketrans("NHPWJXEYOZMAFUSCIGLVTDBKRQ",
                         string.ascii_uppercase)
>>> "DRSA SA XG 1AD AZCEZD XZAAUJZ!".translate(t)
'THIS IS MY 1ST SECRET MESSAGE!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're waaaaaay overcomplicating it. Use the built-in iteration tools that Python gives you.

```
>>> alphabet = "NHPWJXEYOZMAFUSCIGLVTDBKRQ".lower()
>>> message = "VYOL OL FR 1LV LJPGJV FJLLNEJ!".lower()
>>>
>>> table = dict(zip(alphabet, string.ascii_lowercase))
>>> "".join(table.get(char, char) for char in message)
'this is my 1st secret message!'
```

---

### Explanation

The line

```
table = dict(zip(alphabet, string.ascii_lowercase))
```

makes a dictionary of ciphertext letters to plaintext letters. Why? `zip` of two strings gives you a list of pairs: (first letter, first letter), (second letter, second letter), etc. Then `dict` of that makes a dictionary. Then the line

```
"".join(table.get(char, char) for char in message)
```

says to look up each character in the message in the dictionary (and if it's not there e.g. it's a space or a ! then don't change it) and glue them back into a string.

---

By the way, to make a scrambled alphabet all you need to do is

```
>>> alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
>>> random.shuffle(alphabet)
>>> alphabet = "".join(alphabet)
>>> alphabet
'emxcqgzvkruisjtlydbhafopnw'
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach: ta, I always forget about that kinda thing. Edited.